# Timeout reset in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a page with multiple forms on it. Anytime the form is submitted, I increase the value of `actionsInARow` (that is stored in context). What I want to do is, as soon as this value is >0, start a 2 second timer where we will re-fetch data from the database. But, anytime the user submits another form, I want to reset the timer. Below is the implementation I have so far, implemented on the component at the page level. Is there a better way to do this?

```
const [timerId, setTimerId] = React.useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
 if(actionsInARow === 0) {
     return;
 }

 if(timerId !== 0) {
     window.clearTimeout(timerId)
 }

 let timeoutId
 timeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
    setTimerId(0)
    // dispach event in context to reset the count to 0
    dispatch({ type: "RESET_COUNT" });
    
    // re-run fetch request here...
 }, 2000)
 setTimerId(timeoutId);

 return () => {
    if(timeoutId !== 0) {
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    }
 }
}, [actionsInARow]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for one thing you don't need the duplicate code to clear the timeout, the cleanup function will handle that for you so remove those 3 lines in the body. You also don't need the state of `timerId`, unless you're using that somewhere else.

Those changes would look like this

```js
useEffect(() => {
 if(actionsInARow === 0) {
     return;
 }

 let timeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
    // dispach event in context to reset the count to 0
    dispatch({ type: "RESET_COUNT" });
    
    // re-run fetch request here...
 }, 2000)

 return () => {
   window.clearTimeout(timeoutId)
 }
}, [actionsInARow]);
```

Comment: Ah yes, because when actionsInARow is updated, the component re-renders, thus clearing the previous timeout. Thanks!